# Ambiguous Generic restriction T:class vs T:struct

Tags: c#, generics

This code generates a compiler error that the member is already defined with the same parameter types.

```
   private T GetProperty<T>(Func<Settings, T> GetFunc) where T:class
    {
        try
        {
            return GetFunc(Properties.Settings.Default);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            SettingReadException(this,exception);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private TNullable? GetProperty<TNullable>(Func<Settings, TNullable> GetFunc) where TNullable : struct
    {
        try
        {
            return GetFunc(Properties.Settings.Default);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SettingReadException(this, ex);
            return new Nullable<TNullable>();
        }
    }
```

Is there a clean work around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generic type constraints can't be used for overload resolution, but you really don't need an overloaded method for this.  Just use `default` instead of `null`:

```
private T GetProperty<T>(Func<Settings, T> GetFunc)
{
    try
    {
        return GetFunc(Properties.Settings.Default);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        SettingReadException(this,exception);
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Oh, and I've copied your code verbatim, but *please* don't swallow the general `Exception` like this.  Catch the **specific** exception that you **actually** expect might be thrown.  You don't want this code inadvertently swallowing `OutOfMemoryException` or `BadImageFormatException` instances.

Comment: Wish I could +2 for the comment about exceptions. I just recently helped a coworker debug some of his code and it was littered with empty catch (Exception) blocks

Comment: I don't typically swallow all exceptions, this was simple settings property read code, I certainly see where the out of memory exception needs to be thrown, but why would I be concerned about BadImageFormat?  I don't care to stop or bring down the app domain if this code fails for any reason, but out of memory is certainly a good one.

Comment: oh, and the reason I didn't want to return default(T) was the case of an int. I didn't want a 0 coming back as if it was the value.

Comment: @Maslow: If you specify `Nullable<int>` instead of `int` as the type parameter then the default will come back as `null`.  I'm not sure what your settings code read does, but if you need to catch anything more general than `ConfigurationException` then it's possible you're using exceptions as flow control, which will make your project more difficult to test and debug.

Comment: I am attempting to fetch a value from the settings file, if it fails no matter the reason, I don't care I can use a default. If badImage or out of memory happens, this swallowing of not being able to get or set a property will not stop the next piece from throwing those exceptions. This is a non-critical section, and I don't want it to be able to cause unhandled exceptions.

Comment: @Maslow: If those types of exceptions occur, your process is hosed.  Continuing to run could cause serious problems - state corruption, data corruption, etc.  It doesn't matter if the wrapped code is "not critical" - if you just swallowed an `ExecutionEngineException` then all sorts of *critical* code may go wrong afterward, which would not have gone wrong if you had left it alone because it would never have been executed in the first place.  Don't catch `Exception`.  Just don't.  **Especially** in non-critical blocks where you could catch a specific, well-known exception instead.